# Union with char * and asprintf

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C and wanting to make use of a `union`. It looks quite straight forward in a tutorial I'm looking although not using char * but I wouldn't have thought it would have made a difference.

Below is how my union is declared:

```
union MyData
{
    char * targetNumber;
    int callResult;
} myData;
```

Below is my main function which makes use of my union and attempts to store and then read from the union

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    union MyData myData;

    asprintf(&myData.targetNumber, "My Target Number");
    myData.callResult = 1;

    printf("Target Number: %s\n", myData.targetNumber);
    printf("Call Result: %i\n", myData.callResult);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I put it through gdb it looks like the asprintf works, but then when callResult is set targetNumber becomes out of bounds so when I then try to printf it, it segfaults. I've tried using strdup instead of asprintf, but no joy.

Comment: Reading out a member of a union that was not the last member written to is generally considered undefined behavior, and thus is highly dis-recommended and may lead to all sorts of different odd things happening. I would recommend you read up on the difference between a union and a struct, because it seems you have an incomplete understanding of what a union really is/does... You're also not allocating memory for `asprintf()` to write to, with the result you're writing over some random memory somewhere, which may or may not cause a crash, but is a "bad thing" regardless...

Comment: @twalberg You should read about how `asprintf` works: http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yeah, my bad... I forgot what the `a` stood for. It's not a function I use all that often... The rest of the comments still apply, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the difference between `union` and `struct`. If you want to group `targetNumber` and `callResult` in a single structure you would do:

```
struct MyData
{
    char * targetNumber;
    int callResult;
} myData;
```

Then your code should work.

When you define `MyData` as a `union` you are basically creating a type that can be used as either `targetNumber` or `callResult`, but not both at the same time because they occupy the same space in memory.

Let's assume `sizeof(union MyData) == sizeof(targetNumber) == sizeof(int) == 4`, then when you declare `myData`, `myData` will be initialized to zero (`0x00000000`).

```
union MyData myData; // 0x00000000
```

Since `myData` is zeroed, `myData.targetNumber` will also be zeroed which is also `NULL` pointer. `asprintf()` will allocate a new string and populate its contents and
assign it to `myData.targetNumber`. After the call, `myData.targetNumber` will point to some location in memory (say `0x12345678`).

```
asprintf(&myData.targetNumber, "My Target Number");
```

Now you override `myData.callResult` to `1` (`0x00000001`). Since `myData` is a union, this results in `myData.callResult == myData.targentNumber == 1`. You just lost your pointer to the allocated string as `myData.targetNumber` is no longer `0x12345678` but `0x00000001` instead.

```
myData.callResult = 1;
```

This is what will causes your segfault. Since `myData.targetNumber == 0x00000001` and `0x00000001` is not a valid pointer (at least not a valid pointer to a string), this will likely end in a segfault.

```
printf("Target Number: %s\n", myData.targetNumber);
```

If you were to get here, the `myData.callResult` would print normally.

```
printf("Call Result: %i\n", myData.callResult);
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I was the mixing the two together, thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

The error is that you should use a `struct` instead of a `union`. You want to use both `targetNumber` and `callResult`, not either of them, so the proper data structure to store them is a `struct`. With a `union`, they are stored in the same memory location. Consequently, writing to one causes the value of the other to be lost.

Besides, although it is unlikely, `asprintf()` can fail. You should test the returned `int` for negative values.

Note: for what you do with it, `asprintf(&myData.targetNumber, "My Target Number");` might as well be written `myData.targetNumber = "My Target Number";` but I understand that this may be reduced code for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: asprintf would not return a negative number, as it doesn't make a system call, just overwrites the memory at `&myData.targetNumber` perhaps corrupting it and hanging the program.

Comment: @LuisColorado http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf “If memory allocation wasn't possible, or some other error occurs, these functions will return -1”

Comment: I haven't said that a function that is not a system call couldn't fail.  asprintf returns a pointer, and in case of fail, it returns NULL, not -1.  I'm not going to continue this flame war, sorry.

Comment: @LuisColorado `asprintf` returns an `int`: `int asprintf(char **ret, const char *format, ...);`. A negative return value (many implementations specify `-1` but it is not standardized anyway) indicates an error.

Answer (score 1):

union use the same space in the memory. so once you set callResult, targetNumber becomes 0x1. therefore you lost your string, and the new address is so low that should cause a seg fault.

UPDATE: union should be used in bytewise mangling situation. in general purpose data management, it's not as useful as struct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `char *` as a character array.  It's only a variable to hold the address of one (or more) characters.

1. You have to initialize it before dereferencing it. (use of the value pointed to)
2. You have to allocate space to hold the characters you are copying in the asprintf() call.
3. when you write `myData.callResult = 1` you are overwritting (making it unusable) the value stored in the `myData.targetNumber` part of the union (both fields share the same storage)

To allocate data for your union, you have to use something like:

```
union MyData {
    char targetNumber[100]; /* allocate space for 100 characters */
    int callResult; /* space for an integer is shared with the 100 characters of targetNumber */
} myData;
```

If you want to use both fields at the same time, you cannot share the same space, and you will need a `struct` instead, as in:

```
struct MyData {
    char targetNumber[100]; /* allocate space for 100 characters */
    int callResult; /* space for an integer is shared with the 100 characters of targetNumber */
} myData;
```

Try to print `sizeof myData` in both cases, and you will see the difference in storage resources allocated. (the first allocates space for the longest of the fields in the union, whereas the second allocates space for both fields)

Comment: The program in the question is not using a `char *` as a char array. The change to `char targetNumber[100];` is unnecessary and would only even work if other parts of the program (namely, the call to `asprintf` were changed too). In addition, putting fixed limits like `100` in code is a classic security vulnerability.

Comment: using a `char *` can get in a `variable used before initialization` complaint from the compiler (just a warning, but erroneous in this case) and writing where it happens to point to (where?) making memory corruption somewhere.  It does not happen because you are calling a function (asprintf) to do the work, but it's erroneous, you are copying the characters of "My Target Number" in the space of a char pointer variable (normally just four bytes wide) and corrupting the memory.  You probably don't get a crash because the variable MyData has been declared global and is not on the stack.

Comment: If your compiler warns that a `char*` lvalue the address of which has been passed to `asprintf` may be used uninitialized, you should get a better compiler. I do not know of any compiler that warns in such a case.

Comment: you are using a variable parameter function for that, just use a prototyped function with type checking activated and you'll get it.  In some cases you can get gcc warn you about incorrectly passed parameters from analisys of the format string (wich is not present also in the example)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ns6MrCBz . Now please tell me what compiler produces a warning, since you claim that it is a problem.

Comment: Sorry, i did a mistake, asprintf requires a double pointer, so the sample was correct with a `char *`, as asprintf allocates space for the string.  I believed @Boardy was using plain sprintf function.  He also needs a format string, not present in the sample he puts above.

Comment: `"My Target Number"` is a format string. Why would it not be a format string? Are you claiming that `printf("hello, world!\n");` is incorrect C because `"hello, world!\n"` is not a format string?